How to make text automatically take full width after image, I basically need to expand text in L structure
This is what I want to have:

This is what I am getting at the moment.



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr; 
  gap: 20px; 
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto); 
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image {
  grid-row: span 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%; 
}

.content {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2; 
  margin-left: 20px; 
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
  }

  .image {
    grid-column: 1;
  }

  .content {
    grid-column: 1;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/495/495" alt="Image">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
         <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed elit ex. Fusce vitae egestas magna. Vestibulum et aliquet diam. Curabitur vulputate est vel arcu vehicula sollicitudin. Nam iaculis neque nec lorem dignissim lobortis. Aliquam ultricies, dui a volutpat lobortis, ipsum nisi malesuada mi, ut gravida nisl velit et purus. Vivamus volutpat cursus elementum. Sed et nisi eu mauris dictum accumsan et id nisi. Sed bibendum quam velit, nec dictum nibh pretium ut. Fusce volutpat erat hendrerit dictum vehicula. Nam lobortis iaculis ligula in cursus. Sed eleifend sem feugiat, tempor justo vel, pulvinar felis. Quisque ante libero, aliquet sed quam sit amet, hendrerit egestas enim. Fusce fermentum ex sed neque venenatis pharetra.</p>
<p>
In elit neque, elementum sit amet felis eu, dignissim ultricies urna. Duis pharetra lacus sem. Proin maximus ipsum ultricies, commodo dui fermentum, dictum tortor. Vestibulum in ipsum eget ex eleifend consequat. Vestibulum ultrices lorem nisl, quis sollicitudin ex vehicula eget. Nunc eleifend turpis quis facilisis suscipit. Nunc et iaculis diam, et pharetra nisi. Donec sem arcu, imperdiet ut consequat quis, vehicula ac urna. Curabitur nisl enim, volutpat sit amet turpis eget, tristique suscipit neque. Etiam sed sagittis sapien. Sed venenatis dui non dolor tincidunt, eget iaculis urna aliquet. Vestibulum nibh neque, mattis eu nulla quis, tempus dictum velit. Integer vulputate, orci eget rhoncus semper, diam metus volutpat sapien, ut ultrices mi leo eget ex.</p>
<p>
Nunc et ipsum sed lectus facilisis blandit sed id leo. Aenean et dignissim mi. Fusce auctor quam erat, vitae viverra mi tincidunt in. Nunc sodales tortor nec justo elementum, sit amet gravida dolor dictum. Ut at neque ornare, varius metus at, varius risus. Donec porttitor feugiat nulla, blandit lobortis ligula. In consectetur lectus id sagittis posuere. Quisque interdum tempus eros, id consectetur nisl pharetra nec. Cras eget vulputate justo. Phasellus id ante ante. Duis tincidunt tortor eget enim semper commodo. Praesent facilisis purus arcu, et hendrerit nunc condimentum nec.</p>

<p>
Maecenas sit amet vulputate neque, quis cursus lectus. Aliquam eget eros in felis pretium mollis. Curabitur imperdiet, lorem et rutrum rhoncus, turpis mauris pulvinar mauris, et mollis leo enim ut augue. Morbi malesuada, turpis sed dapibus luctus, erat lacus euismod nulla, sed tristique nunc ligula quis ipsum. Nulla pretium facilisis erat, a efficitur eros vestibulum sit amet. Fusce a lectus commodo, suscipit tortor a, tempor risus. Aenean purus arcu, mollis non eros at, efficitur hendrerit dui. Sed pulvinar pharetra neque quis laoreet. Vestibulum lorem tellus, tristique ac augue id, condimentum mattis leo. Phasellus luctus tincidunt euismod. Duis id odio eget mauris feugiat sodales quis et sem.</p>
<p>
Quisque ut tortor justo. Suspendisse mollis purus velit, sed varius leo tempus nec. Suspendisse placerat, ex eu aliquet fermentum, ex risus porta nunc, eget hendrerit dui ex vel odio. In aliquet viverra neque eget dapibus. Phasellus ut ligula arcu. Duis turpis nulla, laoreet id quam at, cursus scelerisque velit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur congue eros felis, et gravida tortor tincidunt a. Ut mollis accumsan lacus, id consectetur elit sodales tristique. Ut commodo hendrerit convallis. Pellentesque tincidunt pharetra tincidunt. Nulla feugiat ullamcorper dapibus. Cras eget efficitur diam. Sed non justo sed urna consectetur pharetra. Maecenas cursus pellentesque tortor ut euismod.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>



Basically, I do not want to create two row and break one row into two col, and let another row to get full width, because the content would be dynamic. I want it to automatically get adjusted, once the image height is completed i want to fill the space below image by the text automatically.

You could get rid of all the extra divs, the gridproperty and simply use float: left; on the image as it was designed exactly for that.

This is snot a grid sturcture. It is a case where CSS float could be correctly used.



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image {
  float:left;
  max-width:300px;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%; 
}



p {
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/495/495" alt="Image">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
         <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed elit ex. Fusce vitae egestas magna. Vestibulum et aliquet diam. Curabitur vulputate est vel arcu vehicula sollicitudin. Nam iaculis neque nec lorem dignissim lobortis. Aliquam ultricies, dui a volutpat lobortis, ipsum nisi malesuada mi, ut gravida nisl velit et purus. Vivamus volutpat cursus elementum. Sed et nisi eu mauris dictum accumsan et id nisi. Sed bibendum quam velit, nec dictum nibh pretium ut. Fusce volutpat erat hendrerit dictum vehicula. Nam lobortis iaculis ligula in cursus. Sed eleifend sem feugiat, tempor justo vel, pulvinar felis. Quisque ante libero, aliquet sed quam sit amet, hendrerit egestas enim. Fusce fermentum ex sed neque venenatis pharetra.</p>
<p>
In elit neque, elementum sit amet felis eu, dignissim ultricies urna. Duis pharetra lacus sem. Proin maximus ipsum ultricies, commodo dui fermentum, dictum tortor. Vestibulum in ipsum eget ex eleifend consequat. Vestibulum ultrices lorem nisl, quis sollicitudin ex vehicula eget. Nunc eleifend turpis quis facilisis suscipit. Nunc et iaculis diam, et pharetra nisi. Donec sem arcu, imperdiet ut consequat quis, vehicula ac urna. Curabitur nisl enim, volutpat sit amet turpis eget, tristique suscipit neque. Etiam sed sagittis sapien. Sed venenatis dui non dolor tincidunt, eget iaculis urna aliquet. Vestibulum nibh neque, mattis eu nulla quis, tempus dictum velit. Integer vulputate, orci eget rhoncus semper, diam metus volutpat sapien, ut ultrices mi leo eget ex.</p>
<p>
Nunc et ipsum sed lectus facilisis blandit sed id leo. Aenean et dignissim mi. Fusce auctor quam erat, vitae viverra mi tincidunt in. Nunc sodales tortor nec justo elementum, sit amet gravida dolor dictum. Ut at neque ornare, varius metus at, varius risus. Donec porttitor feugiat nulla, blandit lobortis ligula. In consectetur lectus id sagittis posuere. Quisque interdum tempus eros, id consectetur nisl pharetra nec. Cras eget vulputate justo. Phasellus id ante ante. Duis tincidunt tortor eget enim semper commodo. Praesent facilisis purus arcu, et hendrerit nunc condimentum nec.</p>

<p>
Maecenas sit amet vulputate neque, quis cursus lectus. Aliquam eget eros in felis pretium mollis. Curabitur imperdiet, lorem et rutrum rhoncus, turpis mauris pulvinar mauris, et mollis leo enim ut augue. Morbi malesuada, turpis sed dapibus luctus, erat lacus euismod nulla, sed tristique nunc ligula quis ipsum. Nulla pretium facilisis erat, a efficitur eros vestibulum sit amet. Fusce a lectus commodo, suscipit tortor a, tempor risus. Aenean purus arcu, mollis non eros at, efficitur hendrerit dui. Sed pulvinar pharetra neque quis laoreet. Vestibulum lorem tellus, tristique ac augue id, condimentum mattis leo. Phasellus luctus tincidunt euismod. Duis id odio eget mauris feugiat sodales quis et sem.</p>
<p>
Quisque ut tortor justo. Suspendisse mollis purus velit, sed varius leo tempus nec. Suspendisse placerat, ex eu aliquet fermentum, ex risus porta nunc, eget hendrerit dui ex vel odio. In aliquet viverra neque eget dapibus. Phasellus ut ligula arcu. Duis turpis nulla, laoreet id quam at, cursus scelerisque velit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur congue eros felis, et gravida tortor tincidunt a. Ut mollis accumsan lacus, id consectetur elit sodales tristique. Ut commodo hendrerit convallis. Pellentesque tincidunt pharetra tincidunt. Nulla feugiat ullamcorper dapibus. Cras eget efficitur diam. Sed non justo sed urna consectetur pharetra. Maecenas cursus pellentesque tortor ut euismod.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>



